# Graph minimum cut with boundary condition restraint

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization

Consider a simple graph $G = (V,E)$ and two disjoint subsets of vertices $S,T \subseteq V$.

Is there an efficient algorithm for finding two subsets $S',T' \subseteq V$ such that $S',T'$ partitions $V$, $S \subseteq S'$, $T \subseteq T'$, and the number of edges with one edge in $S'$ and one end in $T'$ is as small as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W.L.O.G, assume $G$ is undirected. You can address this problem by **vertex contraction**. That is, given $G = (V, E)$ and two disjoint subsets $S$, $T$, construct a new graph $G' = (V', E')$ as follows:

- Create two new vertices $s$ and $t$ and let $V' = \{s, t\} \cup (V - (S \cup T))$;
- For edge $(u, v) \in E$ with $u \in S$ and $v \in V - (S \cup T)$, add $(s, v)$ to $E'$;
- For edge $(u, v) \in E$ with $u \in T$ and $v \in V - (S\cup T)$, add $(t, v)$ to $E'$;
- For edge $(u, v) \in E$ with $u \in S$ and $v \in T$, add $(s, t)$ to $E'$.

Note that the resulting $G'$ may have multiple edges between two vertices. Intuitively, for vertices in $S$ (resp. $T$), we use $s$ (resp. $t$) to represent them all such that if partition $S'$ (resp. $T'$) includes $s$ (resp. $t$), it in fact includes all vertices in $S$ (resp. $T$).

Given $G'$, we can use a maximum $s$-$t$ flow algorithm to find the minimum cut, based on the max-flow-min-cut theorem. It is guaranteed that $s$ and $t$ will not be in the same partition.